# How get long type key ibatis @InsertProvider

Tags: java, ibatis

```
@InsertProvider(type = UserSqlProvider.class, method = "insertSql")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "GENERATED_KEY")
Long insert(Use user);
```

I use ibatas @InsertProvider,and hope get long type primery key after,but this method just Exception:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

whats wrong?

Comment: and i try this,same Exception: @SelectKey(before=false,keyProperty="id",resultType=Long.class,statementType= StatementType.STATEMENT,statement="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id")

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself, like this:

```
@InsertProvider(type = UserSqlProvider.class, method = "insertSql")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "GENERATED_KEY")
void insert(Use user);
```

execute like this:

```
userMapper.insert(user);
System.out.print(user.getId());//use this get id
```